# After Successful uninstall, rollback occurs

Tags: wix, installation, wix3, uninstallation, setup-deployment

I have a program that I am working on the Uninstall for. It involves a chainer that uninstalls all the necessary components, and they all return 0.  However when I look in the directories where the files should have been erased, they are all there.  When I check the MSI Verbose Log for the uninstall it states at about the middle point

> Product: XXXXXXX -- Removal completed successfully.
>
> MSI (s) (E0:04) [10:00:19:651]: Windows Installer removed the product. Product Name: XXXXXXX. Product Version: 5.1.256.1980. Product Language: 1033. Manufacturer: XXXXXXX. Removal success or error status: 0.

Immediately following this point it starts a rollback. I cannot find any indication of an error, nor can I find a reason why it is doing this. It does it for every single MSI. Any thoughts on things I could check to find the solution for this problem would be greatly appreciated.  I have exhausted all my ideas.

BTW I am using WiX to create the MSI, and I have written the chainer that is used for uninstalling myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue! I forgot to end the transaction with commit and apparently the default for ending a transaction is rollback.